# Brother printer - No suitable destination host found by cups-browsed

Tags: printing, brother

I just have gone through a painful migration from my 18 year old computer system to my new system. I had a great plan, but as plans tend to go, they are great until you try to implement them.
Not realizing that you cannot just unplug one drive from a mirror set from non-UEFI system and just plug it into a UEFI system and expect it to work led to several hours of pain. BUT, I digress.
I have read some of the issues other people have had with this print error message. I purged cups-browsed, manually configured my printer to no avail. One inital issue I resolved with the printer was that the VPN was not allowing me to access my printer. I whitelisted my subnet and got past that problem.
The printer is a Brother HL-L2360DW and there is a script provided by Brother to install the printer on a Linux machine. It worked great on my old system, not so good on this one.
I am running the same version of Ubuntu on this machine that I ran on my old system. This system, in case it is germane, has a Gigabyte AORUS X570 Pro MB running an AMD Ryzen 5 5600G. The install, due to the previous issue mentioned above, was a fresh install from the most recent ISO for Ubuntu 20.04. The printer is network connected and I can ping the printer with no issues. Also, I can print to it from my tablet with no issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Had to get some sleep...back. So, I deleted cups_browsed again and tried various ways to install the printer. IPP (can anyone tell me what Queue field expects after the IP address field??), LPD and I get various error messages besides the one above. One time, after adding the printer manually for IPP printing, it indicated that it had spooled 97% and just sat there doing nothing. So, I finally tried to install the printer through the web interface instead of the standard "Printer" option. After entering all the requested information for lpd printing and pressing "add printer", the process hung, just churning away and going nowhere (which is exactly where I feel I am getting on this problem). I am quite sure this is not a network or hardware issue but I must have screwed up something in CUPS during my install.
Again, any help would be appreciated. Thanks
I set up extended logging for cups and the following is an excerpt from that log: (it is pretty big, so I didn't put it all in)

```
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] Returning IPP successful-ok for Cancel-Subscription (/) from localhost.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] Content-Length: 75
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] con->http=0x55c7bc9d5650
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=75, response=0x55c7bc9bee90(IPP_STATE_DATA), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=75
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] Flushing write buffer.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] Waiting for request.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Notifier] state=-1
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Notifier] ippReadFile() returned IPP_ERROR!
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 9] Closing connection.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Server address is "/run/cups/cups.sock".
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Accepted from localhost (Domain)
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Waiting for request.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] PID 2076 (/usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus) exited with no errors.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] POST / HTTP/1.1
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Read: status=200, state=6
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] No authentication data provided.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] 2.0 Cancel-Subscription 10
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] Cancel-Subscription /
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] Cancel-Subscription client-error-not-found: Subscription #312 does not exist.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Returning IPP client-error-not-found for Cancel-Subscription (/) from localhost.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Content-Length: 127
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] con->http=0x55c7bc9d5650
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=127, response=0x55c7bc9cf890(IPP_STATE_DATA), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=127
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Flushing write buffer.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Waiting for request.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 104 (Connection reset by peer)
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 10] Closing connection.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 3] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] [Client 3] Closing connection.
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:16 -0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
I [20/Feb/2022:13:44:17 -0800] Expiring subscriptions...
I [20/Feb/2022:13:44:23 -0800] Saving printers.conf...
I [20/Feb/2022:13:44:23 -0800] Generating printcap /run/cups/printcap...
I [20/Feb/2022:13:44:23 -0800] Saving subscriptions.conf...
D [20/Feb/2022:13:44:23 -0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Dirty files"
I [20/Feb/2022:13:44:23 -0800] Expiring subscriptions..
```

This is the output I got from the following command

```
avahi-browse -rt _ipp._tcp  
+ enp3s0 IPv4 Brother HL-L2360D series Internet Printer local  
Failed to resolve service 'Brother HL-L2360D series' of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
```

Comment: What was the old OS and what is the new one?

Comment: @user:124466 Same O/S, Ubuntu 20.04. Just tried to do a migration

Comment: It's impossible to read your logfile - you should prepend each log line with 4 spaces

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was the original Brother printer (HL-L2360DW). It isn't broken but the printer doesn't work anymore with any of the possible drivers I used with it previously. As a test, I borrowed a printer that has its driver listed in the Ubuntu driver list (Brother DCP7065DN) and it worked just fine. Even though my original printer worked on my old 20.04 system, something changed in the migration with the most current ISO version of 20.04 that doesn't allow my original printer to operate on my new platform. Another unanticipated problem and expense, but the last one, I hope.